# No active device tokens found in Urban Airship in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, urbanairship.com, devicetoken

I am trying to use Urban Airship to send/ receive push notification in my iOS app.

I have created one application, added the urban airship library to that project. I have set the development app key and the app secret key by adding Airshipconfig.plist file in my project. In appdelegate class, I have added the code to register for notification. Now, when I run the application, the device token gets registered in the urban airship dashboard in Audience -- > Device Tokens tab.

But now I want to send the push notification from the dashboard to my iPhone. I did this by clicking

Messages --> Messages Overview --> Message

When I do this, this send the notification to my iPhone.

But there are many questions I dont' understand about urban airship

- I have created the application in development mode, Is it compulsory
  to create an application to production mode also because in
  Airshipconfig.plist, it asks to write the production app key and
  production secret key also.
- In the error console I am getting the message, "No activedevice tokens found", why?
- What is the difference between PushMessage and Message in Messages --> Messages Overview option

Answer (score 0):

- I have created the application in development mode, Is it compulsory to create an application to production mode also because in Airshipconfig.plist, it asks to write the production app key and production secret key also.

Never mix these two. This is most likely your issue. Your app is registering a development device token to a production application. Create a new app in UA's dashboard for each environment:

production > production
development > development

http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/ios.html#production-vs-development-apps-in-urban-airship

- In the error console I am getting the message, "No activedevice tokens found", why?

Probably because of the reason above. Otherwise, are you being prompted to receive push when you open the app?

http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/ios.html

- What is the difference between PushMessage and Message in Messages --> Messages Overview option

no idea what this is referencing.. Screen shot?